# find a two pair from a poker hand in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Hi I need help to work out how to find a two pair from a poker hand. 
I believe I need to count the number of distinct cards which would then tell me if it is a two pair based on the logic that Two pair is a poker hand containing two cards of the same rank, two cards of another rank and one card of a third rank; I'm just not sure how to go about this.

Any help appreciated.

here's my poker cards table

```
+----------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+
| cardName | face | type | suit | faceValue | gameValue |
+----------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+
| AC       | no   | A    | C    |         1 |        14 |
| 2C       | no   | 2    | C    |         2 |         2 |
| 3C       | no   | 3    | C    |         3 |         3 |
| 4C       | no   | 4    | C    |         4 |         4 |
| 5C       | no   | 5    | C    |         5 |         5 |
+----------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+
```

and poker cards hand

```
+----------+--------+----+-----+----+----+----+----------+
| playerId | gameId | C1 | C2  | C3 | C4 | C5 | handType |
+----------+--------+----+-----+----+----+----+----------+
|    12789 | 17MET  | QH | QS  | 3D | 3C | 3H |          |
|    12789 | 82SAT  | 7C | 4S  | 4D | 4C | 3H |          |
|    56347 | 03DEC  | 6S | 3S  | 3H | 3C | 3D |          |
|    56347 | 23WSA  | KH | 10H | 7H | 3H | AH |          |
|    56347 | 30DEC  | AC | KH  | KD | 3D | 3S |          |
+----------+--------+----+-----+----+----+----+----------+
```

I need to get the last row

```
+----------+--------+----+-----+----+----+----+----------+
| playerId | gameId | C1 | C2  | C3 | C4 | C5 | handType |
+----------+--------+----+-----+----+----+----+----------+
|    56347 | 30DEC  | AC | KH  | KD | 3D | 3S |          |
+----------+--------+----+-----+----+----+----+----------+
```

Comment: What is so special about the last row? How is it different from other rows for the same playerId?

Comment: it contains exactly 2 pair

Comment: you mean cardName = c1?

Comment: the last row contains 2 x king, and 2 x three = two pair

@ denny I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Do you have to do this purely in mysql or can you do your processing in a higher language?  It would be a massive pain to do in pure sql, but would be a breeze in python, php, ruby, etc.

Comment: unfortunatly yes - mysql is a must

Comment: I'm not sure if I expressed myself clearly.  The data would still be in mysql, but the checking would be done in another language.  To do it in pure sql would require manually checking all possible combinations - this would be in the area of 30 `OR`ed comparisons inside your WHERE clause.  For the heck of it I can probably write it in an answer.

Comment: No it needs to be done in SQL, as I say I think the statement would be greatly reduced by counting the pairs of cards that are of the same value in each hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about this as a pre-aggregate of each individual card via UNION to get common card regardless of suit.  Then apply a group by...

```
select  PlayerID, GameID, left( c1,1 ) as OneCard
   from PlayerHand 
union all 
select  PlayerID, GameID, left( c2,1 ) as OneCard
   from PlayerHand 
union all 
select  PlayerID, GameID, left( c3,1 ) as OneCard
   from PlayerHand 
union all 
select  PlayerID, GameID, left( c4,1 ) as OneCard
   from PlayerHand 
union all 
select  PlayerID, GameID, left( c5,1 ) as OneCard
   from PlayerHand
```

This would give you something like the following for one person/game

```
playerid  gameid  onecard
12789     17MET   Q
12789     17MET   Q
12789     17MET   3 
12789     17MET   3
12789     17MET   3
```

Now, you can easily see the cards and can do a simple aggregation

```
select
      preQuery.playerid,
      preQuery.gameid,
      preQuery.onecard,
      count(*) as CntThisCard
   from
      ( the entire union query above ) preQuery
   group by
      preQuery.playerid,
      preQuery.gameid,
      preQuery.onecard
   having
      count(*) > 1
```

Per your data, this would return the following rows...

```
playerid  gameid  onecard  cntThisCard
12789     17MET   Q        2
12789     17MET   3        3  This is a full-house
12789     82SAT   4        3  Three-of-a-kind
56347     03DEC   3        4  Four-of-a-kind
56347     23WSA   (not returned in data set)
56347     30DEC   K        2
56347     30DEC   3        2  Two-pair
```

So now, how to extract whatever "hand"  This too would get rolled-up...

```
select
      QryLvl2.PlayerID,
      QryLvl2.GameID
   from
      ( the entire query above returning per-card count ) QryLvl2
   where
      QryLvl2.CntThisCard = 2
   group by
      QryLvl2.PlayerID,
      QryLvl2.GameID
   having
      count(*) = 2
```

In this case, since you are explicitly looking for two-pair, I have the where clause explicitly looking only for cards that had 2 in their hand.  The group by having count(*) = 2 means two distinct cards which would give you the final hand in question.

But as you can see from the second, you can also immediately identify the better hand of 4 of a kind., full house, 3 of a kind, 2 pair and single high card.

You could then simplify the cards table to just the number/face for determining a pair of Jacks/3's is a higher hand than 10's and 9's because you don't care about the suit of the card, just its face value when comparing to other hands.

Comment: Thanks, that's great - much appreciated.

Comment: @eagerzero,  Glad to help... obviously more assessment for more complex hands like a straight, flush, straight-flush, royal flush where all the suits WOULD be qualifiers to the hand analysis.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, it's much better being done in a language suited for such things.  SQL is not the right tool for the job.  As an academic exercise only, this is the statement you need:

```
select *
   from pokerCard
  where (left(c1,1) = left(c2,1) and left(c3,1) = left(c4,1))
     or (left(c1,1) = left(c2,1) and left(c3,1) = left(c5,1))
     or (left(c1,1) = left(c2,1) and left(c4,1) = left(c5,1))
     or (left(c1,1) = left(c3,1) and left(c2,1) = left(c4,1))
     or (left(c1,1) = left(c3,1) and left(c2,1) = left(c5,1))
     or (left(c1,1) = left(c3,1) and left(c4,1) = left(c5,1))
     or (left(c1,1) = left(c4,1) and left(c2,1) = left(c3,1))
     or (left(c1,1) = left(c4,1) and left(c2,1) = left(c5,1))
     or (left(c1,1) = left(c4,1) and left(c3,1) = left(c5,1))
     or (left(c1,1) = left(c5,1) and left(c2,1) = left(c3,1))
     or (left(c1,1) = left(c5,1) and left(c2,1) = left(c4,1))
     or (left(c1,1) = left(c5,1) and left(c3,1) = left(c4,1))
     or (left(c2,1) = left(c3,1) and left(c1,1) = left(c4,1))
     or (left(c2,1) = left(c3,1) and left(c1,1) = left(c5,1))
     or (left(c2,1) = left(c3,1) and left(c4,1) = left(c5,1))
     or (left(c2,1) = left(c4,1) and left(c3,1) = left(c5,1))
     or (left(c2,1) = left(c5,1) and left(c3,1) = left(c4,1))
```

Comment: yeah - that would be over kill alright.. appreciate your time and effort